# Actionscript 3: Using MouseEvent.CLICK and TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, actionscript

I implemented

```
MouseEvent.CLICK
```

across my project to be used on touch and non touch devices. I am now using

```
TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP
```

as this is working better on touch screens.

However, this does not work on non touch devices. So I want to use whichever is appropriate to the platform. My project is deployed to mobile and desktop.

I am hoping a better way exists rather than covering my project in if statements!

```
if (mobile) {
  addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP, closeClick);
} else {
  addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, closeClick);
}
```

Comment: A global variable you set once (to either **TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP** or **MouseEvent.CLICK**) when your app starts, then you refer this variable for event name: **addEventListener(SharedData.CLICKTAP, closeClick);**

Comment: @organis, thanks, but can I ask how you would handle the event sent into the closeClick function, could I just use function closeClick(event:*):void, or is that bad practice?

Comment: Sure, you can. As long as you don't need anything from the event object, it's fine. If you still need something (like **target** or **currentTarget**), you can declare it as most basic **Event** class which both of **TouchEvent** and **MouseEvent** subclass.

Comment: @organis, thanks, just what I was looking for.

Comment: @Organis here, declaring `Event` as receiving type on a listener would do. I wonder what should one declare if requiring a listener for mousedown/drag and touchdown/drag events in a similar app architecture.

Comment: @Vesper, declaring **e** as any (e:*) type would do either as fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Organis suggested, I think defining your own global variable is a good way to do it. If it makes it easier to not have to worry about where and when to set the variable, you could also use a method, or even a getter method, like this:

```
public class EventConfig
{
    public static function get clickTap():String
    {
        return mobile ? TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP : MouseEvent.CLICK;
    }
```

Then you could listen like this:

```
addEventListener(EventConfig.clickTap, myFunc);
```

But beware, make sure your handler functions always have an `Event` parameter and not `MouseEvent` or `TouchEvent`, because you could cause silent failures by passing the wrong kind of event to those functions and there would be no way to catch those exceptions and you'd have a hard time figuring out what's going on.

```
public function myFunc(e:Event):void
```

As a side note, if you're interested in making separate builds for touch screen and mouse, you might look into FlashDevelop's [conditional compilation](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation). You could have a compiler constant that indicates which event type should be used.